# Is creating the same beans for tests in @Configuation violating DRY?

Tags: java, spring

I want to test class A that has a few dependencies from beans B and C. I wonder if copying a code of these beans from program code to test configuration violated dry?

P.S. I am completely new to testing and I do know how dumb the question is.

Comment: This sounds like an [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you want to duplicate the implementation?

Comment: Could you add a sample of `A`, `B` and `C` in order to help you better out in this.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to copy code across from `/main` to `/test`. Spring provides a variety of ways to inject beans into tests.

- First, you can use `@SpringBootTest` to load the Spring Context for your test and then instantiate your class under test using `@Autowired`

  @SpringBootTest(classes = {ClassA.class, ClassB.class, ClassC.class})
  public class ClassATest {

  ```
   @Autowired
   ClassA classA;
  ```

  }
- Alternatively you can mock your dependencies using Mockito (which comes as part of the Spring-Boot-Starter-Test package)

  ```
  @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
  public class ClassATest {

    @Mock
    ClassB mockB;

    @Mock
    ClassC mockC;

    @InjectMocks
    Class A classA;
  }
  ```
- As you mentioned you can also use `@TestConfiguration` to create a configuration for your test and inject those beans into your class using `@Import` and `@Autowired`

  ```
  @TestConfiguration
  public class ClassATestConfig {

    @Bean
    public ClassA classA() {
      return new ClassA(classB(), classC());
    }

    @Bean
    public ClassB classB() {
      return new ClassB();
    }

    @Bean
    public ClassC classC() {
      return new ClassC();
  }
  ```

  }

Then inject the configured bean as so.

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@Import(ClassATestConfig.class)
public class ClassATest {

@Autowired
ClassA classA;
}
```